# TypeError when using whisper-node library for audio transcription in NestJS project

Tags: shift

I'm encountering a TypeError while attempting to transcribe audio from a WAV file using the whisper-node library in my NestJS project. Here's my code snippet:

```
import whisper from 'whisper-node';
import path from 'path';

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads', 'output.wav');
const options = {
  modelName: 'base.en',
  whisperOptions: {
    language: 'auto',
    gen_file_txt: false,
    gen_file_subtitle: false,
    gen_file_vtt: false,
    word_timestamps: true,
  },
};

const transcript = await whisper(filePath, options);
```

I've verified that the file path is correct, and it points to a valid WAV file. However, when I pass this file path to the whisper function, I encounter the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shift') at parseTranscript

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!